# Thymeleaf form comunicar con Controller

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

esto intentando hacer algo tan sencillo como recoger información de un form y enviarla al controlador pero no me deja y no entiendo por qué:

Este es el controlador:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/entregas")
public class ControladorAdminEntregas {
    
    
    
    static final String VISTA_LISTADO = "administracion/";
    static final String REDIRECT = "redirect:/administracion/caches";
    
    @Autowired
    public ServicioEntregas servicioEntregas;
   
  
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getEntregas() {
        
        
        List<Entrega> entregas =  servicioEntregas.findAll();

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(VISTA_LISTADO);
        model.addObject("entregas", entregas);

        return model;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/guardar")
    public Entrega guardarEntrega(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> form) {
        
        
    String n = form.getFirst("nombre").trim();
    String j = form.getFirst("flujo").trim();
    String t = form.getFirst("tipo").trim();
    
    Entrega e = new Entrega(n,j,t);
    //this.servicioEntregas.save(e);
    //List<Entrega> entregas =  servicioEntregas.findAll();

    //ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(VISTA_LISTADO);
    //model.addObject("entregas", entregas);

    return this.servicioEntregas.save(e);
    }

}
```

Esta es la parte del código html donde tengo el form, donde recojo con Thymeleaf la información y la envío al controlador con la etiqueta action:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/entregas/guardar}" method="post" th:object="${entregas}">
                                              
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Nombre</label>
                                                            <input th:name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                                                          </div>
                                                          <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Flujo</label>
                                                            <input th:name="flujo" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                                                          </div>
                                                          <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Tipo Entrega</label>
                                                            <input th:name="tipo" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                                                          </div>
                                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                                        </form>
```

He declarado en el form la variable action de muchas maneras y aun así no me lo coge. Necesito ayuda porque no entiendo por qué no me funciona en este caso particular.

Comment: Hola buenas, Fijate si el problema no sucede porque donde esta el tag de input pones th:name en vez de th:field ya que con th:field lo que hace thymeleaf es buscar un campo del mismo nombre para rellenar. tambien intenta que id sea igual al nombre de la variable que quieras pasar

Comment: Nada no funciona.

Comment: intenta cambiar todos los campos que dicen formGroupExampleInput por el nombre del atributo de la clase con el cual quieres rellenar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución, tan sencillo como que el form que indico en el enunciado estaba **anidado** dentro de otros form lo que causaba conflicto. Una vez extraído a otra parte del código para probar ha funcionado. Gracias